# Excel Formula to return the average of the difference between two ranges of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there any formula that would allow me to calculate the average of the transit periods (Arrival - Departure) of these two ranges of data, without the need of including an extra column? I've tried SUMPRODUCT and SUBTOTAL but no success.

```
Departure   Arrival    
10/11/2015  14/11/2015
30/10/2015  4/11/2015
20/10/2015  27/10/2015
19/10/2015  27/10/2015
10/10/2015  14/10/2015
22/09/2015  29/09/2015
17/09/2015  24/09/2015
26/08/2015  5/09/2015
22/08/2015  26/08/2015
19/08/2015  25/08/2015
19/08/2015  26/08/2015
3/08/2015   13/08/2015
24/07/2015  6/08/2015
23/07/2015  5/08/2015
23/07/2015  31/07/2015
22/07/2015  1/08/2015
21/07/2015  29/07/2015
AvgTransit = ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty simple with an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

```
=AVERAGE(B2:B18-A2:A18)
```

When you enter it, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shft</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> and it will get curly brackets.

Comment: What if I need to apply it only to filtered (visible) values?

Comment: That would be something completely different either using VBA, kutools or some awkward implementation of subtotal. Actually, it might be better to use a pivot table with filters.

Comment: i love you~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

Since average and sum are both linear operations, you can exchange them without affecting the result:

```
=AVERAGE(B2:B18)-AVERAGE(A2:A18)
```

Also possible:

```
=(SUM(B2:B18)-SUM(A2:A18))/COUNT(B2:B18))
```